# Items And List Tabs In Ribbon Don't Show After Editing Page

Tags: list, ribbon, custom-masterpage

In my portal I am running a custom master page.  I have an issue, however, that the `Items` and `List` tabs don't show (even for admin) until I click in an existing list, in which case the ribbon opens.

[image]

Where can I make a change that will allow those tabs to show by default if the user has access?  What can I look for in the masterpage code?

[I found this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26861/hiding-buttons-of-the-ribbon-bar), where it tells how to remove ribbon controls, but it's not what I'm looking for.

---

**[update]**

**THE REAL ISSUE**

*(it's not a custom masterpage issue, so I've edited my title to reflect the true problem)*

On a page where you have a custom list, edit the page and insert a second webpart (in my case, it is a CEWP).  Now the "Page" tab disappears and doesn't appear unless you click in the list somewhere.

I've installed Service Pack 2 for Sharepoint Server 2010, but it doesn't fix the problem.

So, can anyone reproduce this problem?  I've done it now on both my dev machine and in production, and am ready for a solution!  Any clue or comment would be great (even an upvote on my question would be rather nice).

Comment: Can you please show us a screenshot of this?

Comment: Ah, the problem is caused if I edit the page that contains a list.  When I add a webpart, the "Page" tab disappears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, this is a [common problem](https://aleemsheikh.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/list-tools-tab-disappears-from-list-page-in-sharepoint-2010/) (I'm surprised that nobody already had a custom solution).

Apparently, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848892/list-tools-tab-is-no-longer-available-after-adding-webpart-to-the-page) is what causes the problem:

> When you add a web part to the standard list views, the page is no
>   longer classified as a *list view* page, but instead it is classed as an
>   *application page*.

Katrina over on [Stack Exchange posted this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848892/list-tools-tab-is-no-longer-available-after-adding-webpart-to-the-page).

```
    setTimeout(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2");
       if(elem != null) {
            var dummyevent = new Array();
            dummyevent["target"] = elem;
            dummyevent["srcElement"] = elem;
            WpClick(dummyevent);
            _ribbonStartInit("Ribbon.Browse", true);  //set the Browse button as default
        }
    }, 2000);
```

This method will display the tabs above the ribbon, but the problem is that if you click on the page anywhere besides the ribbon itself or in the list, then the tabs disappear again, so it's not perfect, but it *is* sort of a workaround.

I tried the above function without the timeout, and with `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push(whatfunction);` instead, and it seemed to work fine except that the ribbon is quickly opened and close on page load.

Answer (score 9):

This is not a bug.  If you have more than one web part on a page then you must click the one you want the ribbon for.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I tried everything in the world only to realize that i just need to select the right web part. Click on any item on the list to get the ribbons.

Comment: Agreed. This is the correct answer, since it's by design.

Answer (score 2):

Use the designer and put the code in the Content *PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead*

@Colbs on StackExchange: [Question on StackExchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109614/script-editor-webpart-ribbon-problems)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with SharePoint 2013, Clicked on the Return to Classic SharePoint on the Bottom Left and was able to view the Ribbon.

Answer (score -1):

The current view you are in has only become corrupted.  If you access the list settings via site content, delete and recreate the view, the tabs will reappear. I have tested this out in SP 2013.

Comment: This is not true.  It is a bug and I have outlined it in my own answer.  Adding a webpart to a page that contains a list does not corrupt the view.